# Why is Caro, Lady Sula on Zanshaa?

Tags: the-accidental-war, praxis-universe

At the start of [*The Accidental War*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2361645), which takes place 6 years after the end of [*Conventions of War*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?196817), we find Caro, Lady Sula settled back on Zanshaa.  At the end of *Conventions of War*, she had been assigned as military governor to Earth, and seemed fairly pleased to get the position.  She knew that Supreme Commander Tork would never give her a ship command again, and the governorship got her away from him *and* to a place (Earth) she'd always wanted to visit.

I don't recall [*Impersonations*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2051371) very well, but my recollection is that she was doing a competent (if not necessarily popular) job as military governor and she was personally doing reasonably well in the role.  (Certainly by comparison to being stuck on Zanshaa under Tork.)

And yet we find out that she stayed as military governor for only 3 Shaa (2.5 Earth) years.  This is not because of a normal rotation of the job, since we find Lady SCap (Michi) Chen still in command of the Fourth Fleet shipyards for 9 years already by the end of the *The Accidental War*.

Is there any reason for this?  On Zanshaa, until the start of the events of the book, she has spent at least 2 years making futile monthly trips to the Commandery for a ship posting just to maybe annoy Tork.  Why didn't she just stay on Earth?  *Investments* doesn't deal with Sula at all but I haven't had a chance to read *The Stickpin* so I'm hoping that there's a decent justification I'm simply not aware of.  (Or maybe WJW has said something about it?)

Comment: Thank you for bringing to my attention the publication of The Accidental War. Sorry I can't help with the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you've not missed anything. Caroline Lady Sula was appointed to command the Ring Station on Earth. This was intended by Tork as a punishment assignment. In The Accidental War Sula tells Lamey

> I spent three years there, commanding the Ring Station.

So by all appearances the assignment came to a natural end and Tork's enmity ensured that no other position was made available. The suggestion seems to be that Tork could not completely sideline Sula immediately after the war considering her fame, but after a single posting he was able to ensure she was sidelined. Presumably because he'd consolidated his position, while Sula wasn't able to achieve anything of Empire wide note during those three years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I wasn't clear about the "came to a natural end" part, since we've seen other officers who have held postings for significantly longer.  (Lady Michi Chen was noted in this book, but I think there were others in the other books, at least pre-war.)